# Javascript Global Variables Not Incrementing

Tags: javascript

Each time submit button is clicked, I would want the Experience to increment by 1. I have declared Experience as global variable, however the Experience does not go beyond 2.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var Experience = 1;
function scenario1()
{ window.Experience = window.Experience + 1 ;
    alert(window.Experience);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="submit" onclick="scenario1()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The Problem is Post back, once you click the button it will increment the value , then it post back so page reload happens, and the value sets to 1,          so you need to prevent postback.   DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/mbanandetoro6/7SBKp/

Answer (score 4):

Open up your developer tools and watch the network tab.

When you click the submit button, it will:

- Run your function.
- Reload the page

  - Reset the variable.

You need to prevent the page from submitting.

There are two approaches.

**Approach 1: Prevent the submit**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var Experience = 1;
      function scenario1() {
        // Shorthand way to write it
        window.Experience++;
        alert(window.Experience);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
    <input type="submit" onclick="scenario1(); return false">
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Approach 2: Use a button that doesn't submit**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var Experience = 1;
      function scenario1() {
        // Shorthand way to write it
        window.Experience++;
        alert(window.Experience);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
    <button type="button" onclick="scenario1()">Do it</button>
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Extra notes**

Lots of global variables is generally a pretty bad idea.  If this is for a game of some sort, you'd be better putting everything into a `player` object.

```
var player = {
  experience: 0,
  name: "Just some guy"
};

// Grant experience
player.experience += 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<input type="submit" onclick="scenario1()">
```

try this:

```
<input type="button" value="click!" onclick="scenario1()">
```

That way your browser won't try to post something and hit an error.

Answer (score 0):

There actually isn't anything wrong with this. It works, you just need to not use a submit button. Try just a regular input button:  [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls42C/1/)

```
<input type="button" onclick="scenario1()" value="Submit">
```