# How to Increase/Decrease Counter when button is clicked while factoring the value of a dropdown

Tags: javascript

I have a counter which increases/decreases with +1 when a button is clicked.

The buttons are

1. Adds Value

```
<button onClick="onClick()" type="button">ADD MORE</button>
```

2. Subtracts From Total Value

```
<button onClick="onUnClick()" type="button">X</button>
```

Then the value in H6 changes

```
<h6 class="askclient">How Many? <a id="clicks">1</a></h6>
```

My Javascript Code

```
<script>
    var clicks = 1;
function onClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML  = clicks;
};
function onUnClick() {
  clicks -= 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
</script>
```

I need to modify it to also add/subtract the value of a select dropdown to the counter so that the total now factors in the text of the dropdown.
The dropdown:

```
<select id="ddlViewBy"  name="repetition[]">
   <option value="1">None</option>
   <option value="2">1</option>
   <option value="3">2</option>
   <option value="4">3</option>
   <option value="5">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: so, what is your question

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. How should I add/subtract the value of dropdown select to reflect in h6 which displays the total counter? The Add More or Remove works perfectly. I need to factor in the dropdown text.

Comment: @Dan see `++` and `--` syntax [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45620164/2943403) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61947049/2943403) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24338001/2943403).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onChange` to do it.

```
<h6 class="askclient">How Many? <a id="clicks">1</a></h6>
<button onClick="onClick()" type="button">ADD MORE</button>
<button onClick="onUnClick()" type="button">X</button>
<select id="ddlViewBy"  name="repetition[]" onChange="onChange(this)">
   <option value="0">None</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<script>
    var clicks = 1;
    function onClick() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
    function onUnClick() {
        clicks -= 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
    function onChange(elem) {
        clicks += Number(elem.value);
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
        document.getElementById("ddlViewBy").selectedIndex = 0;
    }
</script>
```

Using `Number()` is required because `elem.value` is string.

Force back `selectedIndex` to the None item. Otherwise, if the same number is selected consecutively, `onChange` will not fire.

Comment: I am running into an issue where selecting the same value adds to the already selected value. For Example, selecting 8 adds 8. I need the value to remain the same. So that selecting the same value over doesn't change the total count. We have the default 1 value so selecting, for example, 3, 3 and 5 again or any other number, should result in 6 not 12. (1+5)

Comment: Also, the dropdown appears to have stopped working well i.e selecting a value doesn't display it in the box though the math is working except for the issue I mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: Then delete `clicks += Number(elem.value);`, 
modify `document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks` to `document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks + Number(elem.value);`

Comment: "the dropdown appears to have stopped working well i.e selecting a value doesn't display it in the box".. It's because of doing `document.getElementById("ddlViewBy").selectedIndex = 0;` so delete this. I said "Force back selectedIndex to the None item. Otherwise, if the same number is selected consecutively, onChange will not fire." But your purpose doesn't need it.